# Is multiple pages job in gitlab CI possible?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I am using `gitlab pages` to deploy outputs from the jobs. I have 3 different jobs which produce `html` outputs. One job always runs. 2 other jobs are optional, thus they are manually run.

How is possible to deploy outputs of the manual jobs into `pages` in this situation? Can two different `pages` job be defined in `gitlab ci`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define two different `pages` in `gitlab ci`, the last entry will be seen as `pages` job. Therefore, you need to handle your work inside a single `pages` job.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you can have multiple `pages` jobs but with different names.
It is important to have at least on job that is named exactly `pages`.
Then you can have other jobs that just copy stuff to `public` and they will also be available.

Below is an example of my configuration:

```
pages:  # IMPORTANT! at least one job needs to be named "pages" otherwise the content will not be available
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # copy the pdf file into the public folder
    - mkdir -p public/First
    - cp My_File.pdf public/First
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public  # instruct GitLab to keep the public folder

pages_2:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # copy the pdf file into the public folder
    - mkdir -p public/Second/
    - cp My_File.pdf public/Second
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - public  # instruct GitLab to keep the public folder
```

Also GitLab could release an interesting new feature in the future as discussed here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/277351